# as.numeric changes the actual values as data which is originally a factor.

Tags: r, numeric

When I apply as.numeric, and also as.integer to a column, it changes the values. Why is this? e.g:

```
test <- data.frame(structure(c("52053,34", "79032,83", "20679,06", "20799,56", "20679,06", 
        "21279,45", "51789,44", "54189,45", "73138,89", "73138,89"), .Dim = c(10L, 
                                                                              1L)))
names(test)[names(test) == "structure.c..52053.34....79032.83....20679.06....20799.56....20679.06..."] <- "column"

test$b <- as.numeric(test$column)
test$c <- as.integer(test$column)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test$column` is a factor.

```
class(test$column)
## [1] "factor"
```

`levels(test$column)` shows the labels of the levels of a factor.

```
levels(test$column)
## [1] "20679,06" "20799,56" "21279,45" "51789,44" "52053,34" "54189,45" "73138,89"
## [8] "79032,83"
```

The actual data values are integers: 5, 8, 1, etc.

```
unclass(test$column)
## [1] 5 8 1 2 1 3 4 6 7 7
## attr(,"levels")
## [1] "20679,06" "20799,56" "21279,45" "51789,44" "52053,34" "54189,45" "73138,89"
## [8] "79032,83"
```

The first element of `test$column` is represented by the integer 5 because it is the 5th level.  Looking at the levels vector we see that the label of the 5th level is

```
levels(test$column)[5]
## [1] "52053,34"
```

In general, we want to get the labels of each corresponding element and convert each of those to numeric:

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", levels(test$column))[test$column])
##  [1] 52053.34 79032.83 20679.06 20799.56 20679.06 21279.45 51789.44 54189.45
##  [9] 73138.89 73138.89
```

Alternately try this shorter version:

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", test$column))
##  [1] 52053.34 79032.83 20679.06 20799.56 20679.06 21279.45 51789.44 54189.45
##  [9] 73138.89 73138.89
```

If the numbers were represented using decimal points in the first place (as opposed to commas) then this would have been sufficient where x is such a factor:

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))
```

Comment: This is confusing "levels(test$column) shows the labels of the levels of a factor." surely levels(test$column) returns the levels and labels(test$column) returns the labels?

Comment: @steve, In terms of the nomenclature that R uses there is really only the internal integers that are used to represent a factor and the strings which are used when dislaying the factor and can be extracted using the `levels` function.  A factor consists of the data part which is represented internally using integers 1, 2, etc. and the levels attribute.  There are no other attributes.  If `fac` is a factor then `attr(fac, "levels")` and `levels(fac)` both give a character string of unique values.